# Wait for an onload event before POST (NO jQuery!)

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, onload

I have a function which uses an onload event, lets say it looks like this

```
var doOnload = function(){
    onload = function(){
        //do stuff and return data
        return data;
    }
    onerror = function(){
        //handle error
        return errormsg;
    }
}
```

In the beginning I used a console.log output, but now I need the data to be processed.
The doOnload-function is called by another function. This other function creates an iframe and is writing the data into a form and this is working fine with other functions. Now after the form is filled I want to send the data via POST. This is also working fine. Only the doOnload function is returning 'undefined'.

The iframe/form-filling function looks something like this:

```
//...

input = this.createInputElement('nameOfField1',
  function1());
form.appendChild(input);

input = this.createInputElement('nameOfField2',
  doOnload());
form.appendChild(input);
// ...
form.appendChild(input);
form.submit();
```

and submits the form at the end.

The function 'createInputElement(name, value)' creates an input DOM element with attributes name and value and returns the element. I tried to work with a callback, but i didn't get it to work / did something wrong. I have not much experience working with callbacks.

This is how the createInputElement function looks like:

```
this.createInputElement = function(name, value) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.name = name;
    input.value = value;
    return input;
}
```

Please only tips in js and not in jQuery, thanks.

So how can i send the Post after the onload event is finished and the data is written into the form element?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
David

Comment: why should the `doOnload`return something other then `undefined` there is not `return` statement in it ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added inside the onload / onerror events a return statement. So should I move the return statements outside the events?

Comment: Could you show a working example (like on jsfiddle)?  It's unclear what your code does.

Comment: Your `doUnload` function simply *creates* those other two functions.

Comment: I concur with bfavaretto -- I can't grasp what you're trying to do from your written description...

Comment: Curious... exactly how is your "other function" writing the data into the iFrame forms? What mechanism are you using to do this?

Comment: An working example on jsfiddle will take some time, but gonna try. Another try to explain: 1. create an iframe -> done 2. create an form inside the iframe -> done 3. fill form elements through different functions -> done, except with the onload function 4. send the data via post.

Comment: What does the code in the `createInputElement` method look like? It seems to use the first argument as a name or id to assign to a newly created `INPUT` element and I assume use the second as a callback. One thing I would say is that you shouldn't use `doOnload()` as the second argument there but rather `doOnload` -- `doOnload()` executes that function which is probably useless as an argument to another method.

Comment: with the given informations the call of `doOnload` would set properties `onload` and `onerror` of the window object to these two functions. but where should `onload` get the variable `data` from and why do you return it and where do you expect to be returned. as already mentioned you should make a more clear example.

Comment: What does `function1` do?

Comment: OK now that you have the code in `createInputElement`... the code in `doOnload` *definitely* doesn't make any sense. :-) Especially the onerror part... is your intention that if there's an error it will load the error message into the form field??

Comment: @natlee75 I simply use this to create an iframe: this.iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); this.iframe.name = 'iframe';, then I use form = document.createElement('form'); to create an form with a target attribute 'iframe'. After all inputs are set I do form.appendChild(input); . function1 is just returning a string, or an number. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: Another problem I see is that the event handlers, once correctly attached, would run asynchronously whereas the form would be submitted immediately after your code snippet is completed...

Comment: Maybe something like this... at least a starting point to put you on the right path to a solution...? http://jsfiddle.net/xmtbH/ There's still the issue of how you want to signal that the data has been assigned and the form is ready to be submitted. It's tough for me to know how that would work from just the details you've provided...

Comment: @natlee75 you can say that. If the error ocurrs the message should be loaded into the form field. Also of the onload is successful the result should be loaded into the form field. The main problem is, that the POST is done before the onload/onerror event is finished.